# Jquery Adding a Column before last Column

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a new column when I press the "+" button.

The problem that I have is:

I click the button and it generate a column after the last one.
How Can I do it for generate it before?

I put my table here:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td><input value = "0"/></td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thats the code that I have for the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/2G7Lh/

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$("tr").find("td:last").before('<td><input type="text" value=""></td>');
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Bau3V/)</kbd>

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last/) `td` in each `tr` than insert the element [.before()](https://api.jquery.com/before/) it.

---

You've a Typo too missing `=`

change `<input type"text"` to `<input type="text"` as commented by [Biduleohm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3457169/biduleohm)

Comment: You've a typo: `type"text"` ;)

Comment: @Biduleohm I didn't noticed that ty. corrected .Added it to answer .